# Possible to create Process object for an existing process?

Tags: java

Is it possible to bind a Process object for an existing process? My goal is to be able to wait on an already running process on the system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Get a process given a pid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991819/java-get-a-process-given-a-pid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using the standard `java.lang.Process` class. The only thing I can think of is to  write a script to do the waiting for your, and then invoke that via `Runtime.exec` and wait on it (or use JNI).

The other obvious option is to have your script **drop some evidence of it having finished** (with no errors). The classic evidence would be some kind of file, or row in a database, which your Java application can *spin* on

Comment: Is it possible to perform waiting on arbitrary pid using a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

UNIX systems won't allow the JVM to use the normal underlying system calls on a process that was is not a child of the JVM process.  I think it's unlikely that they've created an alternative implementation.

So you'll probably have to do this some other, platform specific, way.