# Is there a way to get/hook/attach an already running process using java?

Tags: java, process

I want to be able to do something like that:

```
Process p  = getRunningProcess(pid)
```

If there's a way, does it matter how the process was created (using java, using python, from the shell, etc...)?

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3991819/435605

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to attach to another JVM process from Java app (e.g. to be able `to monitor what's going on and potentially detect problems before they happen`). You can do this by using the [Attach API](http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_attach_api). Don't know much about attaching to non-JVM processes.

```
String name = ...
List vms = VirtualMachine.list();
for (VirtualMachineDescriptor vmd: vms) {
    if (vmd.displayName().equals(name)) {
        VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(vmd.id());
        String agent = ...
        vm.loadAgent(agent);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was aiming for non-JVM processes (or more precisely, any kind of process).

Comment: Is there any sample for attaching Junit test case with a test server?

Comment: It requires tools.jar, alternativelly you can use [jvm-attach](https://github.com/mageddo-projects/jvm-attach), no JDK needed

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to attach any non-JVM process with ProcessHandle.

Here a code Example that starts the calculator and closes it by using the pid.

```
    Process calc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gnome-calculator"); 

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    long pid = calc.pid();


    Optional<ProcessHandle> optionalProcessHandle = ProcessHandle.of(pid);
    optionalProcessHandle.ifPresent(ProcessHandle::destroy);
```

But make sure to run Java SE/JDK 11 or higher and to import java.util.Optional;.

See the documentation to see further methods that can be used with ProcessHandle:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html

Credits to [java.lang.ProcessHandle - compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58065946/java-lang-processhandle-compilation-error) for being a template for this.