# java.lang.ProcessHandle - compilation error

Tags: java

I'm running java 11 and trying to use ProcessHandle

```
Optional<ProcessHandle> optionalProcessHandle = ProcessHandle.of(Long.parseLong(pid));
optionalProcessHandle.ifPresent(processHandle -> processHandle.destroy());
```

Getting compilation error:

```
Error:(184, 39) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ProcessHandle
  location: package java.lang
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure your compiler is Java 9 or greater?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, make sure you are actually compiling with Java 11.  If you're using maven make sure that your pom is also on Java 11.

Side note: your second line can be shortened to `optionalProcessHandle.ifPresent(ProcessHandle::destroy);`

Comment: thanks, that was exactly the case. Checked everywhere except Build>compile, silly me ((